# 2n-th derivation of Legendre Polynomial

Tags: derivatives, binomial-theorem, legendre-polynomials

Let $u_n(x)=(x^2-1)^n$
Show that $\frac{(d^{2n}u_n(x)} {dx^{2n}} = 2n!$

$(x^2-1)^n = (x-1)^n(x+1)^n $  and then a should use Leibnitz formula. I thought if I write Leibnitz formula as a binomial I can get it but I couldn’t. Could you please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler: note that $u_n(x)=(x^2-1)^n$ is a monic polynomial of degree $2n$ in $x$, so taking $2n$-th derivative gives $(2n)!$.

And no, $u_n$ itself is not the Legendre polynomial.  which is $u_n^{(n)}$ up to a constant factor.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer but I don’t have any info about monic polynomials yet

Comment: @user519955: Googling is out of the question?

Comment: @darijgrinberg I googled but I couldn’t find. Can you give me a link?

Comment: @user519955 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monic_polynomial for example.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I cannot reach every websites like Wikipedia in my country

Comment: @darijgrinberg thanks for link but since we did not learn it I cannot use monic polynomials in my proof